# Ajax reload only in the first 10 seconds of each minute

Tags: ajax

I'm using this code now and it works.
But i like to refresh only in the first 10 seconds of each minute, so 00, 03, 06 and ,09
Anyone who can help ?

```
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#loaddiv') .load('test5.asp');
}, 3000);

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loaddiv').load('test5.asp')
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change interval to 3 seconds and inside the set interval function check  the current time. Something like

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function ()
                {
                    var second = new Date().getSeconds();
                    if (second > 0 && second < 10) {

                        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
                        $('#loaddiv').load('test5.asp');
                    }
                }, 3000);
```

If you need to execute the code precisely at zero third six and ninth second then you need to set the interval to a 1 second and check if the current second is in the list (0,3,6,9).

Comment: thanks a lot
and i did see that its, off course, important to have to clock at the PC synced with a good timeserver